# How do I create a circuit based on this truth table?

Tags: binary, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, circuit

So this is the truth table

```
   In_1  In_2  In_3  Out
    0      0    0      0
    0      0    1      1
    0      1    0      1
    0      1    1      1
    1      0    0      1
    1      0    1      1
    1      1    0      1
    1      1    1      0
```

I would like to create a circuit based on this truth table.

This is what I have tried, but failed
[image]

Comment: Construct a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and use that to simplify your logic.

Answer (score 0):

A [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) as suggested by [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy), will give you a set of [minterms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minterm) which fulfil the expression. That is the classical way to tackle such problems.

By inspection of the truth-table you can convince yourself, that the output is true whenever `In_1` is unequal `In_3` or `In_1` is unequal `In_2`:

```
f = (In_1 xor In_2) or (In_1 xor In_3)
```

Comment: The question, "How do I create a circuit?" is off topic here. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: Boolean logic, circuits, truth-tables etc. are quite frequent in this forum. Might be a matter of taste, but for me these topics are helpful for programming and software, not just for hardware.

Comment: There is a tag called circuits in Stack overflow